# Android: Navigation drawer item icon not showing original colour

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-navigationview

I am using **Navigation Drawer** in the **fragment** . In the navigation drawer I have a header , text and image, its getting from menu drawer.xml.

The issue is when I launch **Navigation drawer** in my phone the image is shown as gray color.

**XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/transparent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

**drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="Dashboard" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/inbox"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/sho"
        android:title="Sho" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/starred"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/recharge"
        android:title="Recharge " />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/sent_mail"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/add"
        android:title="Add " />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drafts"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/history"
        android:title="Recharge History" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/allmail"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/about"
        android:title="About" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/trash"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings"
        android:title="Settings" />


    </group>
</menu>
```

Actually I want **Naviagtion drawer** like

[image]

But when I launch Application in mobile its getting like

[image]

Comment: have you checked icon of google io app?? icons are not colored its transperent thats why look like that, please download code and check https://github.com/google/iosched

Comment: I check the image , it is not transpernt, In android studio layout page its showing as color, but when lunching the app in mobile it shown as gray @Dhawal Sodha Parma

Comment: for icon remove this line app:itemIconTint="@android:color/transparent" from your xml

Comment: I remove itemIocnTint from xml but no effect @H Rava